# Dynamic DNS update server DNS Host

Tags: dynamic-dns

Could I use dynamic DNS server to update Primary DNS and Secondary DNS settings on router?

My TCP/IP settings are:

```
IP address: 123.43.23.11/24
Default Gateway: 123.43.23.1
Primary DNS: 195.67.19.3 (HERE)
Secondary DNS: 195.67.19.4 (HERE)
```

Using applications that already exists or create ddns server.

//Thanks For any response's (x)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? DynDNS is used to give your router a fixed name. It is not for manipulating which DNS servers your router uses.

Comment: Just had an idea. I though i can connect my router to a specific DNS by using DDNS SRV would be much simpler BEC almost any router supports DDNS but unforchantly for me does not many routers let me set the ip manually (DNS). Can i accomplish this another way? //Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at two different things.

First thing is the DNS servers used by the router. Routers are doing DHCP to get an IP address from the ISP. In the DHCP answer the ISP tells the router which IP address to use and also which DNS Servers use. Some routers offer a web interface where you can override the DNS servers and enter the ones you want to use.

Second thing is dynamic DNS. A router with DynDNS is registering at the DynDNS provider each time he gets a new IP address. This registration can for example be as simple as opening a web page like "http://dyndns-provider.com/register-new-address?dnsname=...&name=...&password=...". Upon registration the DynDNS provider will update the SRV entry in its DNS server so that clients requesting the IP address for your DynDNS name will get the new IP address.

Registering at the DynDNS provider is not related to the router's DNS entries, it has no effect on them. So what you want to achieve is not possible this way.

Comment: could i then use a DHCP server to set the ip address? //Thanks

Comment: The DHCP server is on the WAN (wide area networking) side of the router, it is located at the ISP. If you had access to the ISP's DHCP server, that would be a solution; but you don't have that access. Setting up a local DHCP server will not help you. The router is not looking at the LAN to get an IP address for its WAN/uplink interface.